# How to auto calculate 2 column and display at one column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to alter, the table already created.
Column A + Column B = Column C.
Column A and B already has value, only C don't.
I just need to add function?
If so what is the function?
So next time I just need to add in the column A and B only, cause C already auto calculate

Comment: Yes,I use column A and B as a first value, then put it inside column C

Answer (score 2):

If your table currently has columns A and B but does not yet have C, then you can add it as a virtual column:

```
alter table your_table
  add c number generated always as (a + b) virtual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be024da2bf9cc2c2955e44c449877e2d)

If A and/or B are nullable then you need to handle that; e.g. if you want to treat null as zero for the calculation you can do:

```
alter table your_table
  add c number generated always as (coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0)) virtual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=45c2db1f2342aa6ae35705d3a158e229)

If the column already exists (as suggested by other comments) then you could use a trigger to maintain it for future updates/inserts, which could be as simple as:

```
create trigger trg_maintain_c
before insert or update on your_table
for each row
begin
  :new.c := coalesce(:new.a, 0) + coalesce(:new.b, 0);
end;
/
```

and update existing values as a one-off exercise if needed.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a681b19c7875014c440acae3b9fa7183)

But it would probably be simpler to drop it and re-add it as a virtual column, as it's less work to maintain and prevents the calculated column being directly updated to the wrong value. (Make sure you know what you're doing, and have any required permission/sign-off, before dropping an existing column, though...)

Comment: for the 'c' at trg_mantain_c is column name or command?

Comment: `trg_maintain_c` is just a name I made up for the trigger; make it meaningful for what it is really doing, maybe including the table and column name (or abbreviation) if there is room.

Comment: Less destructive way would be: 1) add virtual column; 2) rename old one; 3) rename virtual column to the old's name; 4) optionally drop old renamed column. This will require less maintenance, less downtime of the table. But I really do not know, if rename turns, for example, view or procedure into invalidated state, when the column "returns" to the table. As a last resort - dbms_redefinition

Answer (score -2):

I think 2 ways to do that in order of what you have:
1 - You use a trigger when you add some data to A and B to automatically calculate C
2 - You create a query that calculate C given A and B

select c = a+b
from table

or something like that

Comment: What I need now is the trrigger to do that, so that I just need to add in column A and B only

Comment: Well you can do a new.C = new.A+new.B

Comment: Is new virtual column ?

Comment: How is your table structured? You have a column C right?

Comment: Column A is BASESALARY, Column B is (EPF and SOKSO) and Column C is  NETSALARY

Comment: If NETSALARY is alredy created, you dont need a virtual column, just write a trigger for new in-data and the query to fill the netsalary column for old data.